# ERROR: Service 'php_fpm' failed to build: unexpected EOF

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

so I'm currenty using docker in my laravel+vue.js project and whenever I try to run docker-compose up --build -d this error appears

```
ERROR: Service 'php_fpm' failed to build: unexpected EOF
```

This my docker-compose.yml code

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  php_fpm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
    container_name: app_php_fpm
    working_dir: ${NGINGX_ROOT}
    networks:
      - app
    volumes:
        - ./:${NGINGX_ROOT}
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15
    container_name: app_nginx
    working_dir: ${NGINGX_ROOT}
    networks:
      - app
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:${NGINGX_ROOT}
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: app_db
    networks:
      - app
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=pfe
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: app_redis
    networks:
      - app
    ports:
      - "6382:6379"
  composer:
    image: composer:latest
    working_dir: ${NGINGX_ROOT}
    command: install
    volumes:
      - ./:${NGINGX_ROOT}
  node:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/npm/Dockerfile
    container_name: app_npm
    working_dir: ${NGINGX_ROOT}
    volumes:
      - ./:${NGINGX_ROOT}
networks:
  app:
    driver: bridge
```

I've checked many forums looking for solutions but none of them seemed to solve my problem. I would really appreciate your help. 
PS : I'm using php version 7.1.28 and docker version : 18.09.2
This is my docker file

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    git \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

RUN docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-libzip
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql zip
RUN curl --silent --show-error https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: your docker-compose is ok the problem seems to be in the dockerfile just throw it here we can take a look

Comment: done ! So do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: cannot reproduce the error you are talking about. got a few others - for example remove the `/` to make make the volume path absolute (change `./:${NGINGX_ROOT}` to `.:${NGINGX_ROOT}`). anyway if you are building a laravel vue app on docker - ive done it before you may check it out  https://github.com/Efrat19/docker-compose